# How to change username via Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm doing a script to change the name of a user just using variables so the user doesn't see the actual command. I have done other things like change the folder of the user but for some reason tryng the same method with this isn't working, I hope you understand my mistakes and give me a hand.

```
echo "Give me the old username"
read name
echo "Give me the new username"
read new
echo "$new" | usermod -l --stdin "$name"
```

For some reason stdin isn't working :C
I'm getting the next output `usermod: invalid user name '--stdin'`.

Note:
I have used stdin to get the new names before and it worked perfectly just this way so I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any `usermod` that knows `--stdin` ... try this:

```
echo "Give me the old username"
read name
echo "Give me the new username"
read new
usermod -l "$new" "$name"
```

Comment: Thanks!
I didn't know that you shouldn't use stdin for this things.
I didn't try it without it cause I never retired the echo.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if you get an error like that, read the man-page. @JesúsAlexisRamírezNavor